# Laravel orWhere() statement on nested eager load

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to run a query where a nested relationship can be archived but also the main Eloquent model can also be archived. I need to return either or both.

A forum thread can belong to many forum categories.

A forum thread can be set as archived.

A forum category can be set as archived.

If the forum category is archived then all forum threads are returned on that category.

If the forum category is not archived but a forum thread is archived then return only those forum threads.

Hope that makes sense.

```
$this->thread = $this->thread->with([
    'user',
    'posts',
    'posts.likes',
    'posts.dislikes',
    'posts.user',
    'categories' => function ($query) {
        $query->orWhere('is_archived', true);
    }
])->orWhere('is_archived', true)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```